# Access all domain users' file in Office365 OneDrive

Tags: api, rest, office365, onedrive

I need to access all users' files in a domain via REST API. I could only access the domain user's files via access token granted via normal OAUTH flow.

I found this article: [Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 Mail, Calendar, and Contacts APIs (OAuth2 client credential flow)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)

This article mentions only Mail, Calendar, and Contacts API. Is File API supported?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Create an access_token as described here https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only and use it in the next steps in the Authorization header
2. Get all the users using this REST API: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
3. Iterate through the users and get their files with this API (adding their userPrincipalName in the url): https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/drive/root/children